# Getting the filename from a file_upload_tag is slow.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where the user selects a CSV file for upload. I want to display the filename using jquery after they select the file. However, it seems that Rails tries to load the whole CSV before I can get to the filename.

The file is selected with

Right now, I am calling the refresh with a button.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#show_file_to_upload").load("/data_updates/selected_file");
    });
});
<% end %>
```

The file name from the file_upload_tag is passed to the partial with

```
<%= render :partial => "/data_updates/selected_file",
 locals: { file_name: params[:data_update].original_filename} %>
```

If I select an 8 kb file, the results are almost instantaneous. However, If I select a 60 kb file, it takes about 30 seconds before I can see the file name.

It seems that the filename when you select a file for upload is not available until the file is fully uploaded.

Am I correct in assuming that the delay is because of the need to fully upload first?

If so, is there a way to grab the filename for display without needing to upload the file first?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that the filename when you select a file for upload is not available until the file is fully uploaded.
>
> Am I correct in assuming that the delay is because of the need to fully upload first?

Yes, if you're going to display the file name after a form submission, the file has to upload first.

> If so, is there a way to grab the filename for display without needing to upload the file first?

Yes, this could be done with pure Javascript, without a form submission.

```
$('#id-of-file-input').on('change', function(ev) {
  alert(ev.target.files[0].name);
});
```

Depending on what your overall goal is, however, this may or may not, be what you're looking for.